# Clear share intent data while whatsapp sharing in android

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap

I have a Relative layout and Textview on it. Then I convert that relative layout to bitmap image and save in directory.

---

The problem is when I am sharing the image, in most of app, I found correct image but in case of whatsapp when I am sharing through whatsapp the preview of sharing image is showing me old one until I close the app. Why it's not getting update and when I share the image on whatsapp, preview is old one and the image goes right one. This works fine in FB, Gmail etc...

---

This is the below code for converting and saving converted bitmap image in file system (directory)

**This is for creating Direcory:**

```
File dir = null;
String directorySubPath = "Android/data/com.domainname.appname/sharedResource/";
String imageNameForSave = "/qqq.png";

if (!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Your device doesn't have external storage.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("SD", "YES", null);
            dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+directorySubPath);
            if (!dir.exists()){
                dir.mkdirs();
            }
            else {
                Log.d("Q-Design:", "Already created", null);
            }
        }
```

**This is for code convert layout to bitmap image & save.**

```
rLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(rLayout.getDrawingCache());
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dir+imageNameForSave);
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
out.flush();
out.close();
rLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

**This is for SHARING that image via Intent:**

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///" + dir + imageNameForSave);

Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test Mail");
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Data Shared with you..."); 
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via:"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dynamic name in **String imageNameForSave**
Ex. String imageNameForSave = "/qqq" + mydate + ext;